# JavaScript variable on HTML

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the value of a JavaScript variable; however, for some reason, `document.write` is not working.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong and if there's another way to do this?  Here is my JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url=${paramValue};
    url = url.replace(/\s/g,"%20");
    document.write("<a href='" + url + "'>" +
        "<img src='/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/image.png'" +
        " width='70' height='20'></a>");
</script>
```

The variable `url=${paramValue};` is working, as I can check it with firebug.
The image is not appearing.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: What do you get if you do this: var url=${paramValue}; alert(url);

Answer (score 2):

What is parsing your url variable? "${paramValue}" is not going to be interpreted by the JS interpreter.

Don't bother manually decoding/encoding URLs in Javascript...just use the built in:

encodeURIComponent(str)
encodeURI(str)

[Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need quotes around your parameter, so the javascript interprets it as a string after the replacement:

```
var url='${paramValue}';
```

But I agree with Hank - use the built in functions.

Answer (score -1):

```
<html> 
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function myfunction(){
    var url = $("#<%=url.ClientID %>").val();
    document.write("<a href='" + url + "'><img src='abc.jpg' width='70'height='20'>    
    </a>");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
   <asp:TextBox ID="url" runat="server" />
   <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="myfunction()" />
</form>
</body>  
</html>
```